# Writing a clustering algorithm with pure python

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

I'm trying to write a clustering code in python without any additional library, just the `math` library allowed. I have 4 centers, stored in a list of lists, something like this: `[[12,3],[0,-8],[-28,20],[1,1]]`.
I also have a long list of data points, as tuples. Something like this: `[(31,3),(10,9),(1,0),(-2,-5), ....]`

I want to calculate the euclidean distance between each center and each point, and store the points according to which center they are the closest to. Something similar to the Kmeans algorithm.

So the output would be a **list of lists**: the first sub-list are the points that are closest to center 1, the second sub-list contains the points closest to center 2, and so on.

This is among my first python tasks so please bear with me. This is what I got so far, I'm making a function that accepts two parameters: points and centers, and returns the list of lists which are the clusters:

```
def cluster_mydata(centroids, points):
    clusters = [[]] * 6
    for i in range(len(points)):
        for j in range(len(centroids)):
            clusters.append(math.sqrt((points[i][0] - centroids[j][0])**2 + (points[i][1] - centroids[j][1])**2))
    return clusters
```

I don't even know how to begin the clustering process, how do I store the data points according to their distance from the centroids? This code generates a list of distances between each center and each data point, not that helpful.

Comment: Sorry, too broad/unfocused for SO. "How to begin something" is not specific enough. You need to do more research. I'm sure you can find many examples of clustering algorithms written in Python with google.

Comment: @timgeb I searched the internet, but couldn't find anything helpful. All I know is that I need to use the `enumerate` function. Could you maybe provide a hint or a starting point for the code?

Comment: @maria does this help? https://gist.github.com/larsmans/4952848

Comment: @L0987 it's too complex, and it doesn't answer my question, it's not straight forward. I'm just having trouble in understanding how to associate each point to it's appropiate cluster. Sorry that my question is too general.